# Redux Toolkit - Can a state update invalidate RTK Query Data?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

We currently have such values set in a settings slice;

```
settingsSlice: {
  projectId: 'a'
}
```

The projectId in the example above is used to compose a dynamic URL that an RTK Query API uses for requests, e.g. `https://projectId...`

Is it possible to invalidate the API data upon a change to the settings slice?

From the documentation, it seems possible to invalidate other API's using tags, but that doesn't seem to be supported within state slices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you would have to manually call `dispatch(api.invalidateTags(...))`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - Wasn't aware I could invalidate it manually :)